# ActiveAdmin menu reloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, inherited-resources

We've a music festival admin that works like a hub for different cities.

For example, `.com/usa/en/admin/` should present the admin for USA festival edition. And `.com/madrid/es/admin` should present the admin for Spain edition.

The pattern is `.com/city/locale/admin`.

The resources (models and pages) should be scoped by the city.

We need to reload menu so items hrefs could be updated.
So, when admin user switch from `/usa` to `/madrid`, all menu links will be updated to point to new `/madrid`.

Comment: Can you show some code? Routes you've defined for scopes?

Comment: @Sarcastic Of course! https://gist.github.com/theo-bittencourt/2cc9114c189cac346c7b1586fdce6c0a